# Number ways to distribute $k$ identical objects between $n$ people so that a special group of $a$ people receive odd number of objects among them

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there is a group of $n$ people, and we need to choose exactly $k$ among them to give $k$ identical prizes. Also, exactly $a$ of these $n$ people are special. The problem is to calculate, how many ways are there to choose the $k$ people in such a way that, an odd number of special people are included in the choice?

For example, if $n = 5,\ k = 3,\ a = 3$ then there are $4$ possible ways. WLOG, we assume that the first $3$ people $p_1,\ p_2,\ p_3$ are special. Then the possible ways are:
$$
(p_1, p_2, p_3)\\
(p_1, p_4, p_5)\\
(p_2, p_4, p_5)\\
(p_3, p_4, p_5)
$$

I know the solution to a similar problem where the constraint of odd special people are not present, so we can pick any number of people from the $a$ special ones and the remaining from the $n - a$ non-special ones. There is bijection argument which shows the answer is simply ${n \choose k}$. But I can't seem to find any way to adapt this solution for the above problem with the odd constraint.

Comment: Already asked six times in the last four days: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4017304/ https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4016941/ https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4016906/ https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4015305/ https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4015246/ https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4013315/

Comment: Sorry about that, thank you for sharing those resources. I'm not very good at searching Math problems, but should have still researched better before asking. I actually got a comment in one of my blogs about an algorithmic question, and the bottleneck of it's time complexity lies in the above Mathematical problem. It can be solved very optimally if the above problem had an O(1) formula for answer. But I guess it unfortunately doesn't.

Comment: I suspect your commenters want this for a programming competition. There is a nice answer. Letting $f(n,a,k)$ be the number of ways, you cannot compute $f(n,a,k)$ in $O(1)$ time, but you can compute the entire list $[f(n,a,0),f(n,a,1),\dots,f(n,a,n)]$ in $O(n\log n)$ time. If you ask the question again after Feb 15, I will happily answer.

Answer (score 0):

The expression:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{a-1}2\right\rfloor}\binom{a}{2i+1}\binom{n-a}{k-2i-1}
$$
hardly can be generally simplified.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to think over the problem and writing an answer. But I wasn't aware that this problem had already been asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4013315/combinatorics-that-looks-similar-to-vandermondes-identity. There seems to be a little simplification to the expression over there. But unfortunately, you're most probably right in saying that, it ultimately cannot be generally simplified.