# Combinatorics simplification

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I was wondering if there was a nice solution to the following, effectively getting rid of the sum:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{i/2}\binom{x}{i-2k}\binom{y}{2k}$$

Note that *i* is even.

I know the following simplifies nicely via Vandermonde's convolution, but I can't bring the equation above to the right state to apply this:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{i}\binom{x}{i-k}\binom{y}{k} \rightarrow \binom{x+y}{i}$$

Comment: Are x,y complex numbers or only naturals? And are they somehow connected to i?

Comment: A month ago MSE was overfilled with questions about odd-index convolution.  Now it is possibly the turn of even convolutions.

Comment: Checking for several values of $x,y,i$, one often gets (in cases where the sum is not $0$ for obvious reasons) numbers with large and apparently unrelated prime factors. This makes an expression as binomial coefficient, or more generally by some multiplicative formula, unlikely.

Comment: If you can give me the simplification for the sum of odd-index convolution, I can then answer my own question :) @user

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4013315/ and the linked questions there. This question has been asked here a lot, no one can find a formula, probably none exist.

Comment: Let $f(x,y,i)$ be this summation, and let $n=x+y$. It takes $O(n)$ time to compute $f(x,y,i)$. However, it is possible to compute the entire list $[f(x,y,0),f(x,y,1),\dots,f(x, y, n)]$ in $O(n\log n)$ time. This is the only simplification I know of.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thanks. I think I need to approach the problem differently then.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I would be interested in your optimisation to get O(nlogn) as the snippet above is indeed part of a wider task which involves exactly what you mentioned. My code at the moment, whilst producing accurate results, suffers from optimisation issues.

Comment: @DragosManta I will if you edit your question so it accurately reflects what you need.

Comment: Or - even better - ask a new question.